# How to force maven to run build-lifecycle before site-lifecycle?

Tags: java, maven, lifecycle

After spending several hours trying to find out whats the problem I come to the conclusion that I need to know:

**How can I force maven to execute the lifecycle phases clean, build and site in exact this order: `clean -> build -> site`?**

Problem / scenario:

I have to multimodule projects with identical moduls:

```
pSuccess
|-pSuccessClient
|-pSuccessEJB (has pSuccessClient as dependency)
|-pSuccessEAR (has pSuccessEJB as dependency)
```

and

```
pFail
|-pFailClient
|-pFailEJB (has pFailClient as dependency)
|-pFailEAR (has pFailEJB as dependency)
```

Both projects have distribution repositories for snapshots and releases in our central nexus artefact repository but none of them has been deployed to it, meaning the nexus is empty.

When I run `mvn clean package site` on the `pSuccess`-project the target directory is deleted (clean-lifecycle), then the modules are all build (build-lifecycle) and finally the reports are generated (site-lifecycle) correctly on the freshly build modules - BUILD SUCCESS! While "debugging" the process I figured out that during the build-lifecycle the needed clientDependency is placed in the lokal maven repository and then used for the EJB, same with the EJB for the EAR module. Working smoothly as expected.

But when I do the same on the `pFail`-project maven executes the site-lifecycle after the clean-lifecycle and **before** the build-lifecycle. As you can expect this results in a failed build as maven can't find the needed dependency (Client) for the EJB. This is quite locically as it hasn't been build yet. I can enforce this result every time I run the command. There's not phase of the build-lifecycle be run - no compilation, just nothing. Maven tries to execute the site-lifecycle first. The build is only successfull when I run a `mvn clean deploy` and then another `mvn clean package site`, becuase then the artefact is read from the nexus. But again site-lifecycle is executed before build-lifecycle. **Note** Building the project only via `mvn clean package` works fine without any problems. All modules are build in the correct order. But when I add the `site` lifecycle it fails.

I read the [maven documentation about lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) but I can't figure out why `site` is run before `build`. In some questions here on SO I read that plugins, which shall be executed in the same phase, are executed in the order they are listed in the `pom.xml`. So I checked that too, but the `<build>` tag is definied before the `<reporting>` tag.

So why is maven executing the site-lifecycle before the build-lifecycle in one of my project and how can I force maven to execute the lifecycles in the right order: `clean -> build -> site` ?

P.S: I run all maven commands on command line in windows 7.

**edit**

I know about the lifecycles and phases, meaning I know what's the differenze between `package`, `install`, `deploy` is - that is not part of the question!

For those who do not believe about the execution order: This is the output when I run `mvn clean install site`, showing that site-lifecycle is executed before build-lifecycle. It doesn't matter if I run `mvn clean package site` or `mvn clean install site`. Again, running single `mvn clean package`(or install) works fine, but not when I want to generate site too. Then site is executed first.

[image: Build-failure]

Comment: For me it seems that it seems that it is running clean, install and site plugins in that order for the parent project. There is just nothing to do for the install/package in mere pom/project. Problem is that it should first take the submodules to the same ride and only then do the site thing.

Are the parent relationships correct (especially versions)?

Comment: @Panu yes they are and I found the cause of the problem yesterday - javadocs plugin. But I hadn't time to wrote an complete answer.

Comment: Good that you managed to sort it out. In retrospective it was fortunate that nobody came up a way to force things to work. That would have hide the actual problem. :)

Comment: Well for some way yeah. I know the problem but I don't understand why it happens so I'm not very wiser than before ^^ But you will see when I find time to post :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging several more hours I found a solution for my problem:

Both projects use the `maven-javadoc-plugin` during for reporting

```
<reporting>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.javadoc.version}</version>
    <!-- DocLint je nach Profil ausschalten (siehe oben) -->
    <configuration>
      <additionalparam>${javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
...
</reporting>
```

In the EJB of the failing project we also use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` in the `generate-sources` phase of the build lifecycle.

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
    ....
  </plugin>
  ...
</build>
```

It seems that both plugins collide during the `generate-sources` phase.

After chaning the `maven-javadoc-plugin` to use the following `ReportSet` the site generation works fine

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.javadoc.version}</version>
    <!-- Disable DocLint correspondening to java version -->
    <configuration>
      <additionalparam>${javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <reports>
          <report>javadoc-no-fork</report>
          <report>test-javadoc-no-fork</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>        
  </plugin>
```

I still don't really understand why it collades but at least my project is working.